# How to call a python script with parsing arguments on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, parsing, jupyter-notebook

I have a python script that I defined:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--task', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--scale', type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ... # Do things with my arguments

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

And I call this script on command line doing:

```
python myscript.py --task mytask --scale 1
```

I would like to call this script in a jupyter notebook. Is there a way to do this parsing the arguments and not modifying my script at all? I.e., doing something that looks like to this:

```
import myscript    
myscript.main(--task=mytask,scale=1)
```

P.S.: I tried using magic line such as `%run` (that probably could work in my case as well) but I had trouble collecting the returns of my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `args` to `parser.parse_args`:

```
# myscript.py
import argparse

def main(args=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--task', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--scale', type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args(args=args)
    print("task is: ", args.task)
    print("scale is: ", args.scale)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output from cli:

```
python3 myscript.py --task aaa --scale 10
# task is:  aaa
# scale is:  10
```

Output from python

```
import myscript

myscript.main("--task aaa --scale 10".split())

# task is:  aaa
# scale is:  10
```

Comment: I was thinking if it would be possible do something letting `def main():`. But this clearly solves my problem completely.

Comment: OP mentioned `%run` in the 'P.S.' of the post. This script would work fine in a notebook being called with `%run myscript.py --task mytask --scale 1` as well. Adding this here more for others looking how to generally run a Python script in a notebook given the title of this post.